# Firebase Cloud Messaging not working on Android with API 28 and lower

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging, but the problem is notification is received only on devices running Android Q. I don't understand why this is happening. My code is quite close to the one provided in the documentation. The most confusing part to me is if it's working on Android Q, then why it's not working on other android versions. MinSDK supported in 21 and targeted is 29.

I've checked and onMessageReceived() function is not triggered in devices with API 28 and lower.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="in.bitotsav.bitotsav_20">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".activities.BitotsavActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.NightsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.FaqActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.SponsorActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.InfoActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.ContactUsActivity" />

    <service
        android:name=".feed.fcm.FeedMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".profile.ui.ProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".schedule.ui.EventDetailActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**FeedMessagingService.java**

```
package in.bitotsav.bitotsav_20.feed.fcm;

import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import in.bitotsav.bitotsav_20.R;

public class FeedMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "FeedMessagingService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
            // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
//                scheduleJob();
        } else {
            // Handle message within 10 seconds
//                handleNow();
        }

    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),                 
remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void showNotification(String title, String desc) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Bitotsav20")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(desc)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    managerCompat.notify(999, builder.build());
}
}
```

**MainActivity.kt** containing code for the notification channel

```
    // create notification channel for BUILD_VERSION >= ANDROID.O
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel("Bitotsav20", "Bitotsav20", 
NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was short on time so I switched to OneSignal. It's also a cloud messaging service. You could check it out if you wish.